# How to change Map<String, List<ClassObj>> to Map<String, List<Map>> in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example;

I want to transform

```
{Aug 07, 2020: [Instance of 'ActivityLog', Instance of 'ActivityLog'], Aug 04, 2020: [Instance of 'ActivityLog'], Jul 29, 2020: [Instance of 'ActivityLog'], Jul 28, 2020: [Instance of 'ActivityLog']}
```

to

```
{Aug 07, 2020: [{MapData}, {MapData}], Aug 04, 2020: [{MapData}], Jul 29, 2020: [{MapData}], Jul 28, 2020: [{MapData}]}
```

Comment: Create a method in your `ActivityLog` class which converts the class into a `Map` representation. Often this method are called `toJson()` since this is often something we want when creating a JSON string out of some objects.

Comment: Please explain how you want to transform. Otherwise any answer here is just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in Flutter reflexion is not possible yet, you do need a method in your ActivityLog to create a map out of the class.

So it can be something like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
    'field1': field1,
    'field2': field2
  };
}
```

Once you have that one, you can use the `.map()` function, like this:

```
var map1 = {
    'Aug 07, 2020': [
      ActivityLog('x1', 'x2'),
      ActivityLog('y1', 'y2'),
    ]
  };

var map2 = map1.map((key, value) {
  return MapEntry(key, value.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList());
});
```